# Get Excel SheetNames using POI jar

Tags: excel, apache-poi, jxl

I need all Excel sheet Names (what r all contains the datas) using POI jar.
Like jxl jar - getSheetNames()

Answer (score 16):

You don't say how you want them, so I'll guess at a list. You just need to iterate over the sheet indicies, getting the name for each. Your code would be something like:

```
File myFile = new File("/path/to/excel.xls");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile);

List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
    sheetNames.add( wb.getSheetName(i) );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get excel sheet names without empty sheets.... As it is in JXL - getSheetNames()......

Comment: You'd have to get each sheet as you went, and check the row count on it. All depends on how you define an empty sheet!

Answer (score 0):

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\TestData.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

```
    int sheetcount = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
    System.out.println("sheetcount: "+sheetcount);
    for(int i=0; i<sheetcount;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(wb.getSheetName(i)+ " ");
    }
```